# VBscript - anyone can help to check what wrong with my script below

Tags: vbscript

```
Dim Nagios
Nagios = http://gl-nagios.fciconnect.com/centreon/index.php
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
call WshShell.Run(nagios, 1, false)

WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys ""
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys ""
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 5000
'Browse to DownHost
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 5000
WshShell.SendKeys "{PRTSC}"
WScript.Sleep 5000
WshShell.AppActivate"C:\AutoScreenCapture\IECapt --url="nagios" --out=C:\AutoScreenCapture\Warning.jpg"
WScript.Quit
```

I intend to use vbscript to login to website and do screenshot on its active webpage and also using IEcapt freeware to capture its screenshot. Not sure where do I go wrong with the script. Any experts advise.

Comment: For starters, you forgot some quotes for your string: `Nagios = "http://gl-nagios.fciconnect.com/centreon/index.php"`

Comment: Noted. it seem like line 25 was the rootcause [WshShell.AppActivate"C:\AutoScreenCapture\IECapt --url="nagios" --out=C:\AutoScreenCapture\Warning.jpg"] dont seem to get it work. I just want to screen the current webpage and save it to jpg.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run a program. But that's not what `AppActivate` does.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues, but before I get to them, let me declare that I am unfamiliar with `IECapt` and how it works.

First, as @bond stated, you need to enclose the `Nagios` assignment in quotes:-

```
Nagios = "http://gl-nagios.fciconnect.com/centreon/index.php"
```

Second, `AppActivate` simply switches to another already-running application window. It looks like you need to run the application with a command line to export the image from the clipboard (you can't switch to an app and apply arguments). Therefore, I suggest you remove the call to `Run` from line 4 and change the `AppActivate` call to the `Run` method so you can start it up with arguments.  Again, not exactly sure how the app works so this may need review.

Third, you have a problem with your string concatenation to insert the url.  You need to use the concatenation operator `&`. To maintain good convention, try to use variable names with the same case as you declared them, in this instance, `Nagios`:

```
'Start up the screen-capture app and minimise it
WshShell.Run "C:\AutoScreenCapture\IECapt --url=" & Nagios & " --out=C:\AutoScreenCapture\Warning.jpg", 2
```

Fourth, I always recommend declaring every variable to avoid runtime bugs and errors.  Therefore, you should always make line 1 of your VBScript files this:-

```
Option Explicit  'Enforce variable declaration
```

Fifth, you haven't declared a variable for `WshShell`:

```
Dim WshShell
```

Finally, you should always release memory for variables that you `Set`:

```
  Set WshShell = Nothing
  Set Nagios = Nothing
```